# How to specify label size or add a legend of a sunburst plot

Tags: r, plot

[image]

Unable to display all labels / specify size or add a legend

```
  library(sunburstR)

# location of file: /Users/alona/Documents/Dr/PhD/Papers/MAS/scoping review/SunburstR/3.csv

sequences <- read.csv("/Users/alona/Documents/Dr/PhD/Papers/MAS/scoping review/SunburstR/3.csv"
                      ,header = TRUE
                      ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

sund2b(sequences, 
       showLabels = TRUE
       ,rootLabel = ' '
,width = "750px"
,height = "750px")[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImIhN.png)
```

Link to the data file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rrfb4Sc4lNVGgMvTbfyxckLZIhZSY-Wg/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a reproducible example e.g. share a sample of data using `dput()` or use a built-in dataset? It's harder to help if we can't run your code as we can't access your data.

Comment: @nrennie - thank you for your comment. I've added a link to the data file used.